# how to return data from ActiveXObject("WScript.shell") to javascript code

Tags: c#, javascript, activex, wsh

I want to return data from my custom program that is called with JavaScript added to my website.

The following sample code calls my program, but I don't known how to return message from a C# .NET program to JavaScript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function runApp() 
  { 
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell"); 
    shell.run("c:\myEXE.exe parm1 param2", 1, True); 
  } 
</script>
```

Using this code, it returns 0, but it's not a solution to the problem

```
var process = shell.run("c:\myEXE.exe parm1 param2", 1, True);
alert(process); // displays 0
```

Comment: Do you realize this will be a security nightmare for your users who will be locked down to IE only and will have to have the exe installed in the correct location on their machine?

Comment: A (somewhat) better approach might be to wrap the .NET program into an ActiveX control itself that can be registered on the system. Then call it directly from JavaScript (in IE only.) Once registered you won't have to provide the install path in the js.

Comment: Nick can you give me example